# App's not installing after download complete?

Tags: updates

I'm facing a problem while downloading apps.I have recently rooted my android which is Samsung galaxy tab 3 smt210r.But after a couple of days i am facing a problem that is when i download an app it does not install.it just disappears from the status bar after reaching 100%

I tried restarting my android,unistalling updates of google play,clearing cache of download manager,google play.but none of them seem to have solve the problem.

please help me as fast as you can.i can not even update any single app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apps download but do not install](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/apps-download-but-do-not-install)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete package folder of downloaded app manually, **if exist** from **phone storage > Android > data**

Reboot device again and download app again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Firelord  please check he have mention in his question that he already tried to clear data of Play store and download manager but problem persists that is why I asked him to try to delete downloaded app data manually **if exist** from  `/data` folder

Comment: Purely my mistake. I interpreted it otherwise.